# ajaxToolkit:Accordion vertical scrollbar on Pane

Tags: asp.net, ajax, accordion

```
        <ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="acc" runat="server">
            <Panes>
                <ajaxToolkit:AccordionPane ID="pane1" runat="server">
                    <Header>
                        <span>&#1047;&#1072;&#1087;&#1088;&#1086;&#1089;</span>
                    </Header>
                    <Content>
                        <asp:Panel ID="controlGrid" runat="server" Height="170px">
```

and It every time makes Vertical scrollbar there even with empty space after Panel on Content.

**How to disable vertical scrollbar and empty space after panel inside 'Content' section ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your panel isn't high enough for its contents. Give the panel a css class with

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Also, make sure you aren't setting the

> ScrollBars

property on the asp:Panel to anything other than "None". I don't see it in your code above, but maybe it's set in the code behind. "None" is the default so if it isn't being set that is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tried ContentCssClass="accordionContent" and

```
  .accordionContent
  {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

it did not work.
But this helps
...

```
  <Content>
      <div style="overflow:hidden">
      </div>
  </Content>
```

...